# what is the best way to get og:image meta property

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to show rss feed links in my website, All going well but its taking so much time to get **og:image** property by using `file_get_contents()` method. Is there any other way to fetch meta tag properties?

Is Python helpful to get these  tags faster ?

Answer (score 12):

This is how I used to get all the og:tags:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
$metas = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
    $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    echo '<h1>Meta '.$property.' <span>'.$content.'</span></h1>';
}
```

Comment: Can't see the purpose of `$queryT = '';` should be dropped if has no use.

Comment: As you can tell, it was a copy paste from a code that I used to use. But agree, I removed it ;)

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
$page_content = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

$dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
$dom_obj->loadHTML($page_content);
$meta_val = null;

foreach($dom_obj->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {

if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 

    $meta_val = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
}
echo $meta_val;
?>
```