# How can I grab the thumbnail from an external url, much like slack does?

Tags: laravel, thumbnails, blogs

[image]

without [Embed](https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed) library.

i'm using Laravel and Vue.js if there is way to get it in Vue.js that's really help full for me.

Comment: maybe look into the library source code? Do some googling and show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i'm using Vue.js with laravel i found a solution in vue.js.

> https://github.com/nivaldomartinez/link-prevue

it show the image as well as detail you can also edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and search for the og:image meta tag from the open graph protocol.

More info on the url below
https://ogp.me

You can use any html php parser

Here is an example of how its done with php
[what is the best way to get og:image meta property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012922/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-ogimage-meta-property)

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question